# Bus error: 10, in C

Tags: c

This code gives **"Bus error: 10"** on execution:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int row, column, tick;
    char *prompt;
    char c;

    ...
    return 0;
    }
```

However, if I comment out the `char c;` declaration, the program runs fine:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int row, column, tick;
    char *prompt;
    //char c; 

    ...
    return 0;
    }
```

I really don't understand what is happening. `char c;` is just a declaration, right? I am not initializing anything here.

Comment: You need to show the complete code.

Comment: Please show a full program that compiles and exhibits the bug you describe.

Comment: Well done, you omitted the essential part only...

Comment: This code *does not* give any errors on execution. Please, post real code.

Comment: Somewhere in your code later, you shoot in a random direction. Without the declaration, you hit something vital and kill something. The declaration moves the vital thing out of the way and causes your random shot to miss. The bug is in the code you snipped.

Answer (score 4):

You are leaving out the part of the program with the bug. The reason your program seems to work if you move a declaration is that you're happening to rearrange the stack so that it works.

Comment: I will look for the relevant section of my code. What do you mean by rearranging the stack?

Comment: the memory for those vars is kept on the stack, so adding or removing one variable will change how much memory from stack is "taken" and how it is arranged, so to say. Likely the problem with your code is to overwrite part of the stack and a specific location that causes that error; addig/removing vars won't remove the bug, but its manifestation.

Answer (score 1):

Which CPU are you running on?

Bus error can mean at least unaligned memory access, which very often is result of accessing memory though uninitialized or corrupted pointer.

Program not crashing or not crashing when removing the char is probably random side effect of changing the code. It doesn't mean anything that it is just that char, any change could make or break it.

You have

```
char *prompt;
```

which is a bit suspicous. It's unwise to leave pointers uninitialzied like that, start by changing that (and every similar place in your code) to:

```
char *prompt = 0; // NULL
```

So you will get segmentation fault instead of memory corruption if you use it before real initialization.